# Wildfly-Swarm + Logstash add tag or costum metadata

Tags: logstash, wildfly-swarm

I have small Wildfly-Swarm application and I have successfully connected it to Logstash using WildflySwarm’s logstash fraction. For my configuration I’m using project-defaults.yml which looks like this:

```
swarm:
  port:
    offset: 10
  logstash:
      hostname: "172.30.3.65"
      port: 9600
      level: INFO
      tag: test
```

The problem is I don’t know how to send tag in logstash. For example I want to send in some information about environment like development test or production. I have also tried it by adding formatter-properties and some metadata like so:

```
swarm:
  port:
    offset: 10
  logstash:
      hostname: "172.30.3.65"
      port: 9600
      level: INFO
      formatter-properties:
        metadata:
          module: "consent-service"
          version: "1.0.0"
          state: "dev"
```

but it does not work. Can this be done using metadata?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain as I haven't tried, but I think `formatter-properties` is looking for a set of key/value pairs that then become metadata within Logstash.

Maybe try changing yaml to:

```
  swarm:
    port:
      offset: 10
    logstash:
      hostname: "172.30.3.65"
      port: 9600
      level: INFO
      formatter-properties:
        module: "consent-service"
        version: "1.0.0"
        state: "dev"
```

Comment: I have changed configuration and Its still not working. I even checked sent packages using Wireshark and there is no metadata in json data beeing sent.

Comment: Ok, then I'm not sure what's missing to make it work. Can you raise an issue for us to look at: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Kiki for raising the issue